# Named_scope at least one in has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User model that has_many :posts. If I wanted to make a named_scope for finding users with at least one post would this be correct?

```
   named_scope :at_least_one_post, :joins => :posts, :group => "users.id"
```

or should I take it a step further and do

```
   named_scope :at_least_one_post, :joins => :posts, :group => "users.id", :having => "COUNT(posts.id) > 0"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I don't think it is necessary to group or add the condition.  Because you are using the `:joins`, that will do an `INNER JOIN` and will therefore only pull users with posts.  If you were going to do an :include, that would `LEFT JOIN` and you would need to add a `HAVING` clause.

So all you should need is

```
named_scope :at_least_one_post, :joins => :posts
```

Comment: you should leave in the :group, otherwise what happens when there are more than one post for the user? You'll get a whole lot of duplicate user records in your result set because of the INNER JOIN.
(unless rails automatically filters that out for you, I forget - even so, why return unnessecary rows from the db?)

Comment: The ORM takes care of the grouping, even on a `LEFT JOIN`.  If you start grouping with the `GROUP BY` statement, then you are going to need to group or aggregate every column in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Is there an easy way to find Users with zero posts?